# GooglePlayGames not signed using an Apple submission certificate

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

Since itunes connect UI have changed I'm expressing problems submitting app updates.

I am using libgdx v 1.3.2-SNAPSHOT' and roboVM v '0.0.14'

The error I am getting from Application Loader:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle
>   'com.google.GooglePlayGames' at bundle path
>   'Payload/IOSLauncher.app/GooglePlayGames.bundle' is not signed using
>   an Apple submission certificate."

Any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to do something?

Comment: No, still trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution! :
The latest update google has done to their iOS SDK 1.7.1 has fixed up everything except for the final GooglePlayGames.bundle which is available in the outdated GooglePlayGames iOS SDK v3.0
As soon as that SDK gets updated, we should be able to use this plugin and validate properly.

As for now you can do it manually by deleting the "GooglePlayGames.bundle/GooglePlayGames" binary.
It won't affect anything since it's just derived data.
Works Perfectly!

Comment: Can you give us more information on how to manually delete the binary? I can't find where it's at or how to delete it.